# Why does my Xbox 360 keep disconnecting from Xbox Live?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

My Xbox 360 keeps disconnecting from Xbox Live at random times for seemingly no reason. No updates happen and I can't earn achievements. When I try to connect back it just keeps telling me that my console cant connect to the internet.

I have an Xbox 360 Slim from 2009. If anyone can help me out I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can troubleshoot your console's internet connection from the settings menu. This will tell you if it is caused by a modem issue, hardware issue, or if the Xbox Live services are unavailable. Right now this post does not offer enough information to determine why you're having intermittent connections but the likeliest cause is simply the age of the console. At more than ten years old, your Xbox 360 may be experiencing hardware failure that prevent it from connecting to the internet.

You can refer to Microsoft's support page for further help fixing the problem: https://support.xbox.com/help/hardware-network/connect-network/xbox-360-network-connection